# How would you convert A string into A Array/ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I have this code in which I want to convert a String (e.g. [15, 52, 94, 20, 92, 109])
to an Array/ArrayList.

I have tried this code:

```
ArrayList<Byte> sdata = new ArrayList<>();
String bytessonvert = new String();
boolean run = true;
System.out.println("Enter Data: ");
String bytes = input.nextLine();
Bytes = bytes.substring(1, bytes.length());
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length(); i++) {
    if (Objects.equals(bytes.substring(i, i), " ")) {
        sdata.add((byte) Integer.parseInt(bytessonvert));
        bytessonvert = "";
    } else if (bytes.substring(i, i) == ",") {
        sdata.add((byte) Integer.parseInt(bytessonvert));
        bytessonvert = "";
    } else {
        bytessonvert = bytessonvert + bytes.substring(i, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: `"a, b, c".split(",", -1)` will result in an array  like `new String[] { "a", " b", " c"}` - using `split("\\h*,\\h*", -1)` it will even eliminate eventual spaces before and after the `,` || `-1` to avoid removing trailing empty strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for bytes. Java handles text well.

Use `String#split` to make an array of the parts.

Make a stream of that array of string parts.

Parse each `String` part into a `Integer` object using `Stream#map` to make another stream of the new objects.

Collect these new `Integer` objects into an unmodifiable `List`.

```
List < Integer > integers = 
    Arrays
    .stream( 
        "15, 52, 94, 20, 92, 109".split( ", " ) 
    )
    .map( Integer :: valueOf )
    .toList() ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/nP6wkV).

Comment: alternative: `Pattern.compile(", ").splitAsStream("15, 20, 30").map(Integer::valueOf).toList()` (not sure if it is easier to read [since it *starts* with a regular expression], probably only a matter of preference)